# CSS3 selector last element that is not of class X

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style the last element of class Y that is not of class X.
Example HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="Y"></div>
  <div class="Y"></div> <!-- this I want to style -->
  <div class="X Y"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried both

```
.Y:not(.X):last-child
```

and

```
.Y:not(.X):last-of-type
```

but they do not produce the desired result in Chromium. I'm wondering if it even can be done in CSS3...

Comment: `:last-child` looks at the last child and `:last-of-type` looks at the type (i.e. `div`), which is why they don't work. There isn't a similar special pseudo-class for checking by class, so it won't be trivial to do this. Your best bet is to select based on other factors of the structure of your HTML.

Comment: If you can use jQuery, `$('.Y:not(.X):last')` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible via CSS Selectors currently.

The desired behavior is only [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#nth-last-match) in CSS Selectors level 4, the one you could need is `:not(.X):nth-last-match(1, .Y)`, but currently no browser supports it.

So, the best solution is to use jQuery as @BoltClock wrote in a comment or to generate the desired class in the html.

Answer (score 1):

you can select the element directly by using the rule:

```
div.container > div:nth-child(2)
```

otherwise, if you know that the last div.y is always continuous to a div.x.y and then comes the end of the parent node, you can select it by using the rule:

```
div.container > div:nth-last-child( 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do not know how many elements precede the element I want to style or how many elements follow. Therefore I can not use the :nth-child or :nth-last-child. I just want to style the last Y that is not also an X...

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
.Y:nth-last-child(-n+3) + :not(.X)
//or 
.Y:nth-last-child(-n+3) + div[class="Y"]
```

EDIT : It il work with random number of element. Check that jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brMWw/1/

Comment: The number of elements preceding and following the element I want to style is arbitrary so I can not use the :nth-last-child. The use of the + operator is interesting... I will look into it.

Comment: Yo can try with random number of element it will work fine. Check that jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brMWw/1/

Comment: @DoubleYo: Won't work if I add another `.X.Y`: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/brMWw/2 That's what Jan-Pieter is referring to.