# for loop , last value

Tags: php, loops, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS3 selector last element that is not of class X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168720/css3-selector-last-element-that-is-not-of-class-x)

I have this loop:

```
for($t=0; $t<$numRowszzx; $t++)
{
    if(!isset($_GET["prodcat"]))
    {
        header("Location: products.php?prodcat=".$rowzx[0]["category_id"]);
    }
    $categoryName = $rowzx[$t]["category_name"];

    if($rowzx[$t]["category_id"]==$_GET["prodcat"])
    {
        ?>
        <li style="height:30px; line-height:30px; color:#2a598a; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"><img src="<?=$site_url?>/images/parrows.png" width="13" height="7" /><span style="padding-left:12px;"><a href="<?=$site_url?>/products.php?prodcat=<?=$rowzx[$t]["category_id"];?>" style=" color:#f15a22; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"><?=$categoryName?></a></span></li>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <li style="<?php if($i > $numRowszzx-1){ ?>margin-bottom:500px;<?php } ?> height:30px;line-height:30px; color:#2a598a; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"><img src="<?=$site_url?>/images/parrows.png" width="13" height="7" /><span style="padding-left:12px;"><a href="<?=$site_url?>/products.php?prodcat=<?=$rowzx[$t]["category_id"];?>" style=" color:#2a598a; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"><?=$categoryName?></a></span></li>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Now what I need is to get the last **li** ...
In this code I need to do if **li** is the last , to give it `margin-bottom:500px;`

```
else {
    ?>
    <li style="<?php if($i > $numRowszzx-1){ ?>margin-bottom:500px;<?php } ?> height:30px;line-height:30px; color:#2a598a; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"><img src="<?=$site_url?>/images/parrows.png" width="13" height="7" /><span style="padding-left:12px;"><a href="<?=$site_url?>/products.php?prodcat=<?=$rowzx[$t]["category_id"];?>" style=" color:#2a598a; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"><?=$categoryName?></a></span></li>
    <?php
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: inline styles are bad practise and you can use CSS Selectors to apply a style to the last li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want last li with `margin-bottom:500px`. Use css for that, don't use inline styles.

You can easily style it by adding `:last-child` to your node.

```
li:last-child {
    margin-bottom:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($t+1 == $numRowszzx)
{
//this is the last iteration
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an *if statement* with the condition $t == ($numRowszzx-1) in your *else*

Something like :

```
else
{
     if($t == ($numRowszzx-1)) // So we reached the upper bound of your for loop
     {
         // Your <li> here
     }
}
```

You might rewrite it as an else if statement, as mentioned by Jimmy.

Comment: If this is the only action in the 'else' statement, you could rewrite this to an 'elseif'. (But I would solve a problem like this in CSS, like Gordon commented above).